# C# / VS / Hosting - ошибка в работе с базой данных MS Sql

Tags: c#, sql

C# / VS / Hosting -  ошибка в работе с базой данных MS Sql

Как eё решить ? - **Решена**

В Visual Studio 2017 подключаю удалённую базу данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде всё хорошо, подключение успешно, но не могу создавать таблицы и вся база совершенно пустая, а кодов ошибок никаких нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если я пробую сделать запрос, то что то всё таки вылетает...
Якобы проблемы с логином.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но совершенно нет никаких проблем с использование Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD после замечаний в комментариях от @Akina**

Делаю с сохранением пароля

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD после замечаний в комментариях от @A K**

Пользователь имеет права db_owner

- Это я продемонстрировал когда использовал Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, т.е. нет не каких проблем с правами для создания таблиц.
- Тех. поддержка выдавала эти права ещё утром.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- и вот ещё из самой базы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD после комментария от @4per**

Это как раз и есть рег.ру

У меня чуть другая, но не пойму как сделать под вашу

Снизу на картинке, судя по всему как раз что то связанно с вашей строкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDDD Как посоветовал @PashaPash - После удаления подключения к БД и перезапуска студии, создав новое подключение по той же схеме, проблема пропала...**

Comment: Ну Вы же НЕ сохранили пароль в свойствах подключения. А ветром его не надует... вот и нет соединения...

Comment: @Akina Только что попробовал с сохранением, ничего не поменялось.
https://image.prntscr.com/image/5tOy9e8KRm6AxycVdOz6pA.png

Comment: Какие права у данного пользователя на сервере БД? Может быть он не dbowner ни разу, а логин для чтения? Хотя судя по мельканию на одном из скриншотов "login failed" -- это неправильно вбит логин/пароль.

Comment: Вы вот там, где *Якобы проблемы с логином.* - попробуйте таки ввести пароль...

Comment: @AK я это продемонстрировал тут https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzh9w.gif
При использовании Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Тот же самый пользователь/пароль.
А вот ещё доказательства того что я не туплю https://image.prntscr.com/image/bSDrHbuhQgucZt9oTb-J6A.png

Comment: @Akina обновил пост с учётом ваших замечаний

Comment: @AK обновил пост с учётом ваших замечаний

Comment: Ваша Connection String соответствует `Server=host;Database=dbname;User ID=adminname;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;` ? Такую использовал на рег.ру...

Comment: @4per обновил пост, но не пойму как подогнать эти настройки под вашу строку.

Comment: студия вполне может лезть с этим именем и паролем в master-базу, , куда вашего пользователя не пускает. пользуйтесь SMSS. Если хотите фикса - вопроизведите ситуацию локально и оформите баг в connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: @PashaPash вот тут нет таких проблем https://youtu.be/0HaZj9k3JKE?t=145

Comment: ну ок, я рад что где-то там в часовом видео проблем нет. Вам стоит все-таки развернуть детали ошибки и привести их прямо в посте, текстом, а не картинкой. и на всякий случай - попробовать удалить подключение, перезапустить студию и создать подключение заново, сразу же сохранив пароль. мало ли что там студия накэшировала.

Comment: @PashaPash после перезапуска студии, проблема разрешилась. Возможно что и в тех.поддержке хостинга изменили, так как параллельно мой вопрос был у них был в работе. Спасибо вас !